# Can someone explain to me why this PHP code works?

Tags: php

I've found this piece of nifty PHP code somewhere online:

```
<?=($__='`@`@'^'*/).')(($_='->.<:'^'__@[_')('>'^@_,'%'^@_)),$__($_('|'^'=','|'^'&')),$__($_(':'^"\n",';'^']'^@_));
```

When you run it, it produces the following string of text:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
```

Why does this work the way it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you start out with is `<?=(value),(value),(value);` so you can rewrite it like this.

```
echo ($__='`@`@'^'*/).')(($_='->.<:'^'__@[_')('>'^@_,'%'^@_));
echo $__($_('|'^'=','|'^'&'));
echo $__($_(':'^"\n",';'^']'^@_));
```

Line 1:

`` $__ = '`@`@'^'*/).' `` uses `^`, which is [the bitwise operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) to shift `` `@`@ `` by `*/).` and set `$__` to the string 'JoIn', next it does this to `$_`, setting it to the string 'range'.

`$__()` and `$_()` are now aliases of [join()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) and [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php).

Making the first line easier to read:

```
echo ($__='join')(($_='range')('>'^@_,'%'^@_));
```

Wrapping pieces in parenthesis serves to set the var and then pass its value as an expression so you can do fancy things like this.

A little cleaner:

```
$__ = 'join';
$_ = 'range';
echo $__($_('>'^@_, '%'^@_));
```

The two args for the inner function: `'>'^@_` and `'%'^@_`, are 'a' and 'z'. (These abuse the [error suppression operator `@`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) to kill a warning and use `_` as a string, so `'>'^'_'` and `'%'^'_'`)

Now you have `echo join(range('a', 'z'));` giving you `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.

Second line passes `'|'^'='` and `'|'^'&'` or `A` and `Z` to those two functions.

And the third line passes `0` and `9`.

The biggest takeaway from this is that you should never use any of these tricks in production code.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you. Never thought I would see such code, you learn something every day :)